# Rest api oauth token empty

Tags: magento-1.7, api, oauth

I'm trying to use REST API access. I followed all the guides found to enable the api and oauth functionalities.
I'm using this code to retrieve the access and then make the request

```
<?php

  class Vashi_Restapi_TestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

    //Basic parameters that need to be provided for oAuth authentication
    //on Magento

         $params = array(
            'siteUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/oauth',
            'requestTokenUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/initiate',
            'accessTokenUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/oauth/token',

            'consumerKey' => '3157bsm22p5q80t7zcujfi9uzxafefic',//Consumer key registered in server administration
            'consumerSecret' => 'zo22y43t1d63okihubfgkg39rdg3pjvl',//Consumer secret registered in server administration
            'callbackUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/restapi/test/callback',//Url of callback action below
        );

        // Initiate oAuth consumer with above parameters
        $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
        // Get request token
        $requestToken = $consumer->getRequestToken();

        // Get session
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        // Save serialized request token object in session for later use
        $session->setRequestToken(serialize($requestToken));
        // Redirect to authorize URL
        $consumer->redirect();

        return;
    }

    public function callbackAction() {

        //oAuth parameters
        $params = array(
            'siteUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/oauth',
            'requestTokenUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/initiate',
            'accessTokenUrl' => Mage::getBaseUrl().'/oauth/token',
            'consumerKey' => '3157bsm22p5q80t7zcujfi9uzxafefic',
            'consumerSecret' => 'zo22y43t1d63okihubfgkg39rdg3pjvl'
        );

        // Get session
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        // Read and unserialize request token from session
        $requestToken = unserialize($session->getRequestToken());
        // Initiate oAuth consumer
        $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
        // Using oAuth parameters and request Token we got, get access token
        $acessToken = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, $requestToken);
        // Get HTTP client from access token object
        $restClient = $acessToken->getHttpClient($params);
        // Set REST resource URL
        $restClient->setUri(Mage::getBaseUrl().'/api/rest/products');
        // In Magento it is neccesary to set json or xml headers in order to work
        $restClient->setHeaders('Accept', 'application/json');
        // Get method
        $restClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
        //Make REST request
        $response = $restClient->request();
        // Here we can see that response body contains json list of products
        Zend_Debug::dump($response);

        return;
    }
}
```

I tried also the admin, customers and guest access but the result is always:

```
An error occurred. Your authorization request is invalid.
```

It seems the oauth token is not being generated as the url I can see is:

```
http://magentohost/oauth/authorize/?oauth_token=&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fmagentohost%2F%2Frestapi%2Ftest%2Fcallback
```

Really struggling with it, any advice?
thanks

UPDATE:
Tryied the apache configuration proposed but it still not working.

I was able to obtain the token using ruby oauth client, still not working via PHP

```
oauth \
  --verbose \
   --query-string \
   --consumer-key 3157bsm22p5q80t7zcujfi9uzxafefic \
   --consumer-secret zo22y43t1d63okihubfgkg39rdg3pjvl \
   --access-token-url http://magento.host/oauth/token \
   --authorize-url http://magento.host/oauth/authorize \
   --request-token-url http://magento.host/oauth/initiate \
   authorize
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a problem of `mod_rewrite` OR `SymLinks`.

Please enable `mod_rewrite` :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Now edit `apache config` file :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and replace this code :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note: changed `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`

Now restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` and check. This may fix your issue.

Comment: this is actually the confirguration: <Directory "/home/testing/public_html">
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/testing/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/testing/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
</Directory> is not already ok?

Comment: just add these lines (shown in answer) `<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted </Directory>` to apache config file